# GDM is flashing and I can't login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gdm

I recently switched to Ubuntu GNOME from Windows and am very inexperienced. I was using Ubuntu fine for a while. But this morning I had trouble signing in because my login prompt continuously refreshes and it's impossible to type more than 2 letters before it is cleared. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried logging in using a TTY?  Press Ctrl + Alt + F3.  If you can log in the issue is with GDM, and I'll help you get that sorted out...